# PHP ZMQ is not working on Windows but will work on Linux?

Tags: php, zeromq, ratchet

PHP ZMQ bundled with ratchet is not working on windows but will work on Linux. When its running on linux the message will output to the server console. The same script will not work on Windows. It's running but not receiving any messages.

I've installed XAMPP with PHP 7.2. I've copied the following files to the directions shown below. (https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows) using thread safe version. Both x64 and x86

DIR: C:\xampp\php
libzmq.dll
libzmq.pdb

DIR: C:\xampp\php\ext
php_zmq.dll
php_zmq.pdb

I've restarted apache and called php from command line as follows:
php push-server.php

The server runs but when visiting the "post.php" from the browser "Done" is echoed but no message is ever received in console.

I've disabled windows Firewall, Windows UAC, Running Command Prompt as Administrator.

post.php

```php
// This is our new stuff
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'PUSHER');

    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
    $socket->send("Hello World");

    echo 'Done!';
```

pusher.php

```php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface {

    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
        echo 'Subscribed'."\r\n".$topic;
    }

    public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {

    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    }
    public function onCall(ConnectionInterface $conn, $id, $topic, array $params) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->callError($id, $topic, 'You are not allowed to make calls')->close();
    }
    public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
        // In this application if clients send data it's because the user hacked around in console
        $conn->close();
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {

    }

}
```

push-server.php

```php
require '../application/vendor/autoload.php';
require('pusher.php');

    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

    // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself

    $pull->on('message', function ($msg) {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    });

    $pull->on('error', function ($e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    });

    // Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                )
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );

    $loop->run(); 
``


The expected result is "Hello World!" in server console on Windows however nothing is ever shown.

The same script works on Centos 7 with the same version of PHP and ZMQ.
```

Comment: To save somebody the time. I've also tried this with SSL. No luck.

Comment: To save somebody the time. I've also tried changing ports. No Luck.

Comment: I had the same issue even without getting into SSL, Windows 11 with XAMPP, PHP7.2. PHP-ZMQ support for Windows seems have stopped at 7.2. I guess we need to use Ubuntu for anything related to PHP/ZMQ from now on.

Answer (score 0):

This has strangely just started working. All I did was disable SSL. Im confused as you are.